# Webpack use AMD define

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to convert my company project, from JSPM and systemJS to webpack.
So i started a new project from scratch and instaled basic configuration.

I need to include in the project a old package that was build by former collegues. The package was develop in Jquery and use the AMD define method.

So I searched and found [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader).

In my webpack configuration I have:

```
{
      test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor/module/module.js'),
      loader: "imports-loader?this=>window&define=>false"
},
```

And in my code I have the follow:

```
import Module from 'module';
new Module.WindowManager(arg1, arg2);
```

When I run the webpack, I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: module/wm/window missing module/core/emitter
```

In the module that im trying to use the module/core/emitter are use here:

```
define('module/wm/window', 
    ['module/core/emitter'], function (Emitter) { ... });
```

Comment: so, first question: the error says it can't load module/core/emitter, *does it exist on disk*? If so, does your config that regulates where `define` can find things point to the correct directory?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans About first question, the module/core/emitter is defined in the same file of the module im trying to import. Don't understand the second question. which config are you referring? is the webpack config?

Comment: I created a github project reproducing the error that i mention.
https://github.com/jcrjaci/webpack-tests

Comment: webpack doesn't use `define`. The only framework I know that uses that is require.js, so my first guess is you have some require.js code that you haven't properly configured during your rewriting effort. That github project tries to pack an already minified .js file, so that makes... well, no sense really. Why are you trying to bundle an already bundled library?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans because that minified js need jquery to be global. if i import that minimfied js and jquery in the html it worked. But i whould like only to managed my external packages throught webpack and npm.

Comment: You missed the point: why do you even have a minified "deskum.min.js". What is it, and why are you not bundling that the normal way since you're now using webpack.

Comment: Because that file is the output from another project that is used in this project. i have the normal file too (not minified). are u saying that i should included the normal file and bundle it with the webpack?

Comment: yes. Or, if that bundle relies on specific externals, [set the correct externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) so that webpack doesn't try to interpret them.

Answer (score 1):

After reproduce you code, use `amd` with `webpack` it's fine.

Your code just miss these id dependency `deskum/core/emitter` and `deskum/core/promise`. Make sure check those `id` have `define`. I have try remove those dependency and it's work

[image]

as you can see the screenshot, I can set `Deskum` to property class `this.deskum` from `window` but `this.deskum.Window()` have throw error because I removed `"deskum/core/emitter","deskum/core/promise"` at `deskum.min.js`.

Just make sure all dependency included, see [documentation](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD#dependencies-).

Comment: if i include the jquery and deskum.min.js in the html. It works. But i want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: you can add jquery via `webpack` using `ProvidePlugin ` (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery)

Comment: add keep use `deskum.min.js` with `import-loader`

Comment: I'm not sure with `"deskum/core/emitter","deskum/core/promise"`, but It seems not define and from outside libs, right? @Jacinto

Comment: I dont think so. In the current project the deskum.min.js is loaded through System.js.  No reference to `deskum/core/emitter` outside the deskum.min.js file

Comment: I'm not sure `"deskum/core/emitter","deskum/core/promise"` do, I saw in deskum.min.js not declared just reference. can you just make sure it? And try add declare like `deskum/tpl/template`